# How to avoid 2 plots being wrongly mixed?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm facing an issue when running my code. In summary, it covers some data muggling until the data is available to be plot, using matplotlib. In order for just to ilustrate the case, I put the general idea / result above:

```
#Code for Graph 1, which mixes 2 plots together

plt.xticks(rotation=90)

plt.bar(list_a,list_b,label="Spent", color="orange")

plt.bar(list_c,list_b, label="Count of spent", color="black")

plt.title("Graph 1")

plt.legend()

plt.savefig("Graph 1")


#Code for Graph 2

plt.xticks(rotation=90)

plt.plot(list_d, list_e,label="Cumulative spent")

plt.grid(color="grey",linestyle="--",linewidth=1)

plt.title("Graph 2")    

plt.legend(loc="lower right")

plt.savefig("Graph 2")
```

The result is:

Right for Graph 1:
[image]

Wrong for Graph 2:
[image]

The Graph 2 should be as the following (I could generate it rightly when using Jupyter Notebook instead of PyCharm):

[image]

So, in general, the Graph 2 is considering also the data from Graph 1... Any guesses on how to avoid this? I tried to use sleep(), but it has not worked it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try calling `plt.close()` after you're done working with each plot.

`If you are creating many figures, make sure you explicitly call pyplot.close on the figures you are not using, because this will enable pyplot to properly clean up the memory.`

ref: https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html