# How to make matplotlib save a figure/plot correctly when used in conjuction with plt.cla() , plt.clf() and plt.close()?

Tags: python, matplotlib, io

I have a plotting function script that plots a linechart and save the plot figure in an string buffer.To test the plots, I am calling the plotting method in a loop. I am using the "Agg" backend as I am just saving the plot and not displaying it in a window. My script and the call to the method looks like this:

```
def plot_linechart(year, month, data, annotate=False):
  ....plotting data formatting ....
  linechart_fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,6), layout='tight')
  ax = linechart_fig.subplots()
  ax.plot(x_axis_data, y_axis_data)
  ... plt.fill_between()... // to color weekends/holidays

  if annotate:
     ...annotate some more things in plot
  buffer = io.StringIO()
  plt.savefig(buffer, format='svg', bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0.1)
  plt.cla()
  plt.clf()
  plt.close(linechart_fig)
  return buffer

for month in range(1, 13, 1):
  chart_without_annotation = plot_linechart(2013, month , data, False)
  chart_with_annnotation = plot_linechart(2013, month , data, True)
  ...send these plots to somewhere else in my application that displays them in a pdf viewer...
```

I am calling the plt.cla(), plt.clf() and plt.close() to clear memory and also because, without them, the plots would sometimes get mixed and generate wonky plots.

But since I have added plt.cla(). plt.clf() methods, I no longer get the two plots mixed up. But for my first plot, sometimes I get an empty plot.

Could it be because plt.savefig sometimes cannot save the plots fast enough before I clear the figure? This is unlikely because savefig() is synchronous in nature as mentioned in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54711019/why-wont-my-python-async-await-actually-write-matplotlib-files).
Does plt.cla()/plt.clf() somehow clear/overwrite what's already saved in my buffer??

I tried to clear the figure following the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61551562/how-to-avoid-2-plots-being-wrongly-mixed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757348/how-to-clear-memory-completely-of-all-matplotlib-plots#comment130154983_65910539) and still have trouble saving my plots properly.

Answer (score 0):

`buffer` will only return the memory adress of your saved plot. If you want to get your svg as string, you can use [`getvalue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO.getvalue):

```py
def plot_linechart(year, month, data, annotate=False):
  ....plotting data formatting ....
  linechart_fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,6), layout='tight')
  ax = linechart_fig.subplots()
  ax.plot(x_axis_data, y_axis_data)
  ... plt.fill_between()... // to color weekends/holidays

  if annotate:
     ...annotate some more things in plot
  buffer = io.StringIO()
  plt.savefig(buffer, format='svg', bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0.1)
  plt.cla()
  plt.clf()
  plt.close(linechart_fig)
  return buffer.getvalue()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do get the value using returned_buffer.getvalue() after I make the method call, use bs4 to extract the contents within the <svg></svg> tags and send them to to a pdf generator.

Comment: You mean the problem remains? If so please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question.

Comment: I am unable to attach Tranbi's username after an @ symbol to reply to his comment.
But I seem to have solved the issue by using plt.show() and plt.close(linechart_fig) after the plt.savefig() statement. I was under the impression that plt.show() wouldn't do anything here, as I am just saving the plot and not actually displaying it in a window.

Comment: Don't need to include @Tranbi in a comment here, he will get notified automatically for comments on his answer. Though not sure why you cannot write his name after the @ symbol.